# MSBuild and Jenkins: where to put credentials?

Tags: git, visual-studio, msbuild, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am trying to set up a small continuous integration server using Jenkins, Git and MSBuild.
I have read so many different tutorials on this topic but I still have so many questions!

I created a Jenkins job which will pull changes from Git and deploy to another server with MSBuild.

The build action is calling MSBuild.exe and takes the following properties:

```
/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0
/p:Configuration=Release
/p:Platform="Any CPU"
/p:DeployOnBuild=True
/p:DeployTarget=Test
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://myserver:8172/MsDeploy.axd
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
/p:UserName=myusername
/p:Password=mypassword
```

It is working happily, but I would like to know more. For example:

1. I am specifying the credentials as properties. Is there a better way to go? Please note that the deployment server is external (not in LAN)
2. Do I need to use the `/P:CreatePackageOnPublish=True` property? If yes, why?

Until now I have tried to follow the following tutorials:

- http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity.html
- http://www.infoq.com/articles/MSBuild-1
- http://www.jayway.com/2012/10/17/a-simple-continuous-integration-and-deployment-workflow-with-asp-net-mvc-github-and-jenkins/

Comment: What are your credentials being used for that you are using with the /p switch?

Comment: Web Deploy authentication on the target server (IIS or machine user).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I would recommend not building a .sln or .csproj file directly.  But write a mini-msbuild-definition file (usually .proj) and put some parameters in there.  (And keep your command line call simpler)
2. Then your question changes slightly to "how do I store credentials".  I usually store them in a standalone file.

This url shows how to protect the "sensitive info" file.

[Encrypting password in a MSBuild file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16662100/encrypting-password-in-a-msbuild-file)

I like to store my info in a small xml file, as seen here:

[FTP Credentials for MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Communication.Ftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377738/ftp-credentials-for-msbuild-extensionpack-communication-ftp)

Here is an example of a "basic msbuild (.proj)" file. (Below link)

This is for CC.NET.  But the philosophy is the same.
Do very little hudson/jenkins/cc.net/other propietrary calls.  Use a .proj file for 99% of what you need to do.  and think of your CI (jenkins/cc.net/other) as a "super fancy msbuild executor"

[How to setup building steps for CruiseControl.net from repository of the building project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404845/how-to-setup-building-steps-for-cruisecontrol-net-from-repository-of-the-buildin)

Comment: Thanks granadaCoder, I will explore this way of encrypting credentials in another file. What about the /p:CreatePackageOnPublish parameter?

Comment: That gets coded into the .proj file.                     <MSBuild Projects="$(WorkingCheckout)\MySolution.sln" Targets="Build" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)">
            <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="TargetOutputsItemName"/>
        </MSBuild>

Comment: Sorry, I meant what is that parameter for? What does it actually do?

Comment: I don't know about that one, sorry.